# SBT REPL loops really long input strings

Tags: input, sbt, read-eval-print-loop, mintty

I am running `sbt 0.13.7` on `mintty 1.1.3`.

When I put really long string in `sbt` REPL it just loops the input as follows:

```
sbt> aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaabbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb
```

And if I put more chars, I get (every new line is what I get when I put a char):

```
sbt> aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaabbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb
bbt> aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaabbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb
bbt> aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaabbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb
bbb> aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaabbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb
bbbb aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaabbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb
bbbbbaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaabbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb
bbbbbbaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaabbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb
```

I expect to get:

```
sbt> aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaabbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb
bbbbbb
```

How to fix this?

Comment: What do you mean by `in just loops the input`? Do you mean it echoes back the input? What is your actual problem? What do you expect?

Comment: I expect string to be `> aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaabbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb` and `bbbbbbbbbbb` on the next line, instead of everything on the same line overlaped.

Comment: Sorry but this is still unclear. Maybe you can make it more clear by providing the exact input and output you get.

Comment: I tried to record terminal session in Windows, but with no success. I reformulate in another way.

Comment: Does it make sense now?